# OrientDB collection expanding and grouping

Tags: java, orientdb

I have following classes in my DB:

1. Goods{name:String, price:Double, ...}
2. OrderSpec{goods(1-1):Link, quantity:Double}
3. Order{spec(1-*):LinkList, date:Date, ...}

Then I have to select all goods from orders with particular date, group it and make some aggregates e.g. sum of quantity for each goods. In stadard SQL DB I'd do couple joins, filter by date and group by goods_id but can't figure out how to achieve that in OrientDB. I've started from

```
select expand(spec) from Order where date = "..."
```

But when I add grouping:

```
select expand(spec) from Order group by spec.goods
```

The result is empty.

In general I would like to find equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
select goods_id, goods_name, sum(order_spec_quantity), sum(goods_price) from Order
    left join OrderSpec on order_id = order_spec_order_id
    left join Goods on goods_id = order_spec_goods_id
where date = 'some date'
group by goods_id, goods_name
```

Comment: Can you specify the fields type of OrderSpec and Order?
OrderSpec and Order are vertexes or documents?

Comment: Thanks for remarks, I added field types in my post. All entities are documents.

Comment: sorry @Aeteros, but the field spec(1-*) of the document Order is a link or a linklist ?

Answer (score 0):

with OrientDB you could opt for the Graph DB to remove the PK and FK fields from the your DB by using directly Vertices and Edges.
I created an example with code and queries:

```
create class Goods extends V;
create property Goods.id integer;
create property Goods.name String;

create property Goods.price double;
create property Goods.description String;

create class Order extends V;
create property Order.id integer;
create property Order.dateorder date;
create property Order.country String;

create class orderSpec extends E;
create property orderSpec.quantity integer;

insert into Goods(id,name,price,description) values (1,"oven",260.5,"kitchen");
insert into Goods(id,name,price,description) values (2,"television",300.7,"sitting room");
insert into Goods(id,name,price,description) values (3,"bed",100.3,"bedroom");
insert into Goods(id,name,price,description) values (4,"table",120.4,"dining room");

insert into Order(id,dateorder,country) values (1,"2013-04-12","UK");
insert into Order(id,dateorder,country) values (2,"2014-07-12","Germany");
insert into Order(id,dateorder,country) values (3,"2014-07-12","UK");

create edge orderSpec from (select from Order where id=1) to (select from Goods where id=1) set quantity = 2;
create edge orderSpec from (select from Order where id=1) to (select from Goods where id=2) set quantity = 3;
create edge orderSpec from (select from Order where id=1) to (select from Goods where id=3) set quantity = 2;
create edge orderSpec from (select from Order where id=2) to (select from Goods where id=2) set quantity = 1;
create edge orderSpec from (select from Order where id=3) to (select from Goods where id=2) set quantity = 1;
create edge orderSpec from (select from Order where id=3) to (select from Goods where id=4) set quantity = 2;
```

And this is the graph:

[image]

Now you can query the DB to get all the informations without join operations by using the direct links between the Vertices.

Filtering by article:

[image]

Filtering by date:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for so detailed aswer, but it not covers grouping. Also my DB uses documents, will it work with in() and out() methods?

Comment: Here you can fiind an example of GROUP BY:

Comment: select article, sum(id) from (select out('orderSpec').name as article, id, dateorder from Order unwind article) group by article

Comment: For your second question, you must use the Graph DB type if you want to use in() and out() functions to traverse the graph through the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
select myRid,myName,sum,eval("myPrice * sum") as totalPrice from (select myRid,myName,sum(myQuantity) as sum,myPrice from (select spec.goods.@rid as myRid,spec.goods.name as myName,spec.quantity as myQuantity, spec.goods.price as myPrice from (select spec from Order where date = 'some date' unwind spec )) group by myRid,myName)
```